# Existing ledger and a new network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

What happens if the ledger is taken out and attached to a new fabric network? especially in the below case

1 Fabric is used for storing confidential data among 3 parties.(via chaincode abac, chaincode multi ownership among 3 parties so there are three ledgers synced)
2 One party(party A) takes out the ledger and setup a new hlf behind and attaches the ledger to the new hlf and changes the chaincode in order to see all the data.......

In this scenario what can be implemented to prevent the party A from seeing the data.....isn't it true that the ledger is taken out so the ledger is just a chuck of file(impossible to function as long as it is not in the original HLF setup(the orginal hlf network.......even ip change blow up all the ledger and setting......).....

Look forward to your replies

Answer (score 0):

For any given peer or orderer that is part of a Fabric "network", some person or entity will inevitably have physical access to the platform on which it is hosted.  They will be able to physically read the ledger file(s) as well as the state database(s).  So if they are not supposed to have access to the data, then you either need to encrypt the payloads at the application layer or you can use private data collections.

Comment: Hi thanks. it's so weird because it can be applied to all the HLF network cases. for example even the channel functionality is broken up by the above scenario if one of network participants who owns the ledger physically takes out the ledger secretly and attaches it to his private hlf then removes or newly setup the channel setting etc.....then the protection provided by the channel in the original hlf becomes useless...The ledger seems to function as a ledger only if it runs on its original hlf network.....

Comment: Right - there's no magic when it comes to the ledger.  You should take a look at private data collections as they enable the use case where data resides only on the peers/nodes which need access.  And with private data, the orderer nodes do not have access to the actual data - just hashes.